# Difference between having User Profile Sync service running on App server and on both App and Web servers

Tags: user-profile-service, userprofile-sync

Way back some of our company employees had configured User Profile Sync Service on both App and WEF servers.
Now we are in a situation where we have to stop User Profile sync service stopped on the Web Front Server. 
But i am unware of what is difference it makes 'User Profile Sync service running on App server only and running on both App and Web servers'
What will be the difference on actual sync functionality. What will be difference performance, maintenance. Any other difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You sure that sync service is running on two servers.

What I believe it is user profile service instance started on two server and he did because of failover thing. Like if one end point failed then 2nd available for UPA to work. You can stop this on one server as long as it is running on one server

You can't have sync service running on two servers unless you have two UPA service application configured.

You can go the central admin > system settings > manage server inthe farm...on this page can you share the screen shot ( cut the server names just right side info).

Comment: Hi Waqas,
Thank you for your reply. I understood. Just wanted to reconfirm that stopping Sync service wont make any difference to the actual functionality of synchronization.
Kindly confirm...

Comment: again, are you talking about SYnc service or User Profile service, could you please share the screen shot of the server(hide the server name etc)...then i can tell u exactly